# Error when writing remix unit tests: URL not parseable: remix_accounts.sol

Tags: unit-testing, solidity, remix

I'm writing unit test in remix-ide and I want to call functions from different addresses within a single test.

The [remix-tests Github page](https://github.com/ethereum/remix/tree/master/remix-tests) says that you can use `import "remix_accounts.sol";`, but I get `URL not parseable: remix_accounts.sol`. How to fix that? Or maybe there's another way to call from various addresses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import files with relative paths, in your case, modify the following

```
import "remix_accounts.sol";
```

to

```
import "./remix_accounts.sol";
```

---

Also, notice that remix doesn't allow import from an ancestor directory, for example:

```
import "../remix_accounts.sol";
```